# How to get list of filenames and filesizes using C#

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint

I am trying to get list of filenames and file sizes from a SharePoint site using C#. Does anyone have code for that?

Or is there any best way to achieve that.

My Requirements are:

1. Get all the list of filenames and file sizes from Sharepoint folder.
2. Store the details in excel.

Comment: What SharePoint version? What have you tried looking at and implementing so far?

Comment: Do you mean all the files from Sharepoint list?

Comment: You will need to tell us: Which SharePoint version? On-prem or in the Cloud? Where will the C# code be running? On the server? On a client PC? In a custom web part? In a custom SharePoint page?

Answer (score -1):

You could do it using the PnP Powershell Cmdlets.

```
$folderUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Custom"

$ctx = Get-PnPContext

$folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $folderUrl

$ctx.Load($folder.Files)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

https://veenstra.me.uk/2017/03/20/office-365-officedev-pnp-powershell-get-all-files-in-a-folder/

You should be able to work a `| export-csv <location>` in to pipe it to a CSV file too.

Comment: Answers need to be self-sufficient. You need to provide the relevant information here, in the answer itself, with the link being used only as a reference. If the content is not here in the answer, and the off-site location is unavailable for some reason, the answer has no value here.